# Unsupported length() function generated for SQLite in scalaquery

Tags: scala, scalaquery, slick

When trying to use scalaquery to retrieve the length of a text column in a SQLite database it generates the wrong SQL.
I get this:

```
SELECT "t1"."title" FROM "GoodPages" "t1" WHERE ({fn length("t1"."title")} > 65)
```

when the query should really be

```
SELECT "t1"."title" FROM "GoodPages" "t1" WHERE length("t1"."title") > 65
```

The `for` comp I use for getting this query is

```
for (f <- Foo if f.title.length > 65) yield f.title
```

And the Table def I have is

```
object Foo extends Table[(Int,String)]("Foo") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def title = column[String]("title")
  def * = id ~ title
}
```

It seems like scalaquery is just generating the wrong `length()` function, but I can't find where in the code this happens nor have I found anything on the Internet about this.

Answer (score 1):

The generated SQL you see uses [JDBC escape syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc1020262.html), more precisely [JDBC escape syntax for fn keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html). This syntax can be used by JDBC drivers but unfortunately is not supported by the SQLite driver.

Slick 1.0.0 knows this as the following snippet from `SQLiteDriver` suggests

```
case Apply(j: Library.JdbcFunction, ch) if j != Library.Concat =>
  /* The SQLite JDBC driver does not support ODBC {fn ...} escapes, so we try
   * unescaped function calls by default */
  b"${j.name}("
  b.sep(ch, ",")(expr(_, true))
  b")"
case s: SimpleFunction if s.scalar =>
  /* The SQLite JDBC driver does not support ODBC {fn ...} escapes, so we try
   * unescaped function calls by default */
  b"${s.name}("
  b.sep(s.nodeChildren, ",")(expr(_, true))
  b")"
```

If Slick 1.0.0 doesn't work for you we can probably find another solution. Let me know.